# PHP syntax error in SELECT mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-order-by

I am trying to execute this mySQL query in PHP.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Property 
        WHERE CONCAT(name, '',
                     contact_number , '', 
                     hostel_address,'',
                     renter_name,'',
                     other_details,'',
                     date_posted,'') LIKE '%".$var."'
        ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_posted,'%d/%m/%Y')";
```

**An I am getting following error:**

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_posted,'%d/%m/%Y') ASC' at line 1

Any help here :(

Comment: Think there is a missing `'` in `'%".$var." ORDER `.

Comment: Replace `LIKE '%".$var." ` by `LIKE '%".$var."' ` and `...date_posted,''` by `date_posted`

Comment: if you're using prepared your statement you wouldn't have this concatenation problems in the first place

Comment: @NigelRen Thanks for the suggestion, it is still giving the approx. the same error.

Comment: @Ghost could you elaborate more. Please?

Answer (score 0):

may try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Property WHERE CONCAT(name, '',contact_number , '', hostel_address,'',renter_name,'',other_details,'',date_posted,'') LIKE '%".$var."' ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date_posted,'%d/%m/%Y')";
```

Note that there should be an ending single quote before ORDER BY

Comment: Yep. I have made it corrected.But it is still giving approx. the same error.

Comment: @Saleh_Ninja could you please paste the new error message to comment?

Comment: @Saleh_Ninja `CONCAT(name, '',contact_number , '', hostel_address,'',renter_name,'',other_details,'',date_posted,'') AS ConcatenatedString` ? try that

Comment: @Grace I have already edited the question with new error. Please again have a look

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile no effect.